# Editing columns that are automatically sorted

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet with chores.
I classify each between 1-9 on the column B.
1 I can do later and 9 I need to do almost immediately.

Column C is the place of the chore.
If B is 9 then C is 1.
If there are two of the same the newest of them receive a lower position.

```vb
Sub Order()
    Dim colB As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Set colB = Range("B:B")
    
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Range("A2:U" & lastRow).Sort Key1:=Range("B2"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes

    For i = 2 To lastRow
        Cells(i, "C").Value = i - 1
    Next i
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Works for new entries, but I need to be able to edit the numbers in column C, like if I want a chore 3 to be the top of the line, or to lower a 9 chore.

Comment: Welcome to SO. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

[Lets say your worksheet looks like this (and has a date and time stamp)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k80sL.png)

If your worksheet does indeed look that way, then you could utilize Excel's native 'custom sort' which should give you a list in the order you wish. So: if the chores are of the same urgency/type(1-9) and the newest is sorted lower (receives a lower position), then the code would look like this (here's the code):

```
Sub Filter()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim lastRow As Integer: lastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    With ws.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=ws.Range("B1"), Order:=xlDescending, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SortFields.Add Key:=ws.Range("A1"), Order:=xlAscending, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SortFields.Add Key:=ws.Range("C1"), Order:=xlAscending, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SetRange ws.Range("A1:C" & lastRow)
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

If you wish to use an array approach and assign scores, let me know, regardless here's additional code to get you started down that path:

```
Dim arr As Variant: ReDim arr(1 To lastRow - 1, 0 To 4)
For r = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
      arr(r, 0) = ws.Cells(r + 1, 1).Value 'column A (Chore)
      arr(r, 1) = ws.Cells(r + 1, 2).Value 'column B (Class)
      arr(r, 2) = ws.Cells(r + 1, 3).Value 'column C (Age)
      arr(r, 3) = ws.Cells(r + 1, 4).Value 'column D (Place)
Next r

For r = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
      Debug.Print "Chore: " & arr(r, 0) & " Class: " & arr(r, 1) & " Age: " & arr(r, 2) & " Place: " & arr(r, 3)
Next r
```